# how to fix 23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android

All of a sudden I cannot get Gradle to build any projects under Android Studio.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. 
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

My Gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.marathon.simplelist"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Even if I create a new Blank Activity project I still get this error.

I have Android Studio 1.3.1 installed with

SDK Platforms: 5.X, 5.1, 5.0, 4.4, 2.3.3
SDK Tools: SDK Build Tools, SDK Tools 24.4, Platform-Tools 23.0.1

Obviously something is reconfigured locally since even a new empty project will not build.  Ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Try setting `compileSdkVersion 23`

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 25):

First try to clean and rebuild your project from Build menu.

Step 1: go to **Build -> Clean Project**

Step 2: go to **Build -> Rebuild Project**

This should solve your problem.

Otherwise **try updating Android SDK build tool from SDK manager** and modify your build.gradle to use latest buildToolsVersion i.e "23.0.2" as of now

Answer (score 9):

see gradle console output,

in my case - :app:processDemoReleaseResources FAILED

it was cyrillic file name in asset folder

Comment: Yes I have same problem....and its solved..!!  **Check Your file name in asset folder..!**

Comment: Saved my life from hours of figuring out

Answer (score 6):

If someones is using `react-native` (and have updated it's version recently) and having this problem:

Quoting @chamchamgo:

> I found the root cause is that old version's packager collect
>   resources (image etc.) and put under
>   $(rn_project)\android\app\src\main\res, while newer version put them
>   under
>   $(rn_project)\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\$(buildType).
>   It brings duplication which leads to failure of task
>   'processReleaseResources'. And it also explains why new created
>   project works well. When you have an old RN project upgrading to newer
>   version, just delete directories like 'drawable-xxxx' (ATTN：no 'v?'
>   postfix) under $(rn_project)\android\app\src\main\res and wolrd will
>   be nice.

Check the whole thread at:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5787#issuecomment-236408669

Answer (score 5):

Goto `gradle.properties` under Gradle Scripts
then set `android.enableAapt2=true`
clean and Rebuild the project

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue and worked for hours on it and finally found out the solution. 
The drawable file that I referred in my xml was not existed. I removed the code and rebuild the project. It worked.
My advice if anyone face such an issue, please look into your **res** folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help, your suggestion saved a lot of time for me

Answer (score 3):

You may miss the some resources.

You can find the exact problem using following steps

1. Click -> gradle (right side)
2. Goto app-> Tasks -> build -> assembleDebug
3. Double click **assembleDebug**

You will get the exact error. you can fix your problem

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using wrong string resource id in a layout file. After I fixed it and rebuilded the project the error was gone. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi I just logged on today to see that apparently I downvoted this answer. I didn't - at least not knowingly! And it can't be undone, apparently - I've asked support. So errrr sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

this error happened when you delete any resource as image which is used in any file  the android studio rise this error

the solution

Build -> clean project
Build -> rebuild project

good luck

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit too late to answer, but I didn't find a perfect answer, so here what worked for me:

- make sure that all your files/fields in /res/ are correct.

I renamed couple of fields in attrs > declareStylable so they were pointing to non-existant enums and that's what caused a error for me.

Comment: Ye, I had the same issue. In two modules I had duplicated attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If the error is occuring while Gradle Processes Resources, then it is most likely an issue with your resources. Check your gradle console to make sure.

Double check any recent changes that you may have made to the `res` folder.
In my case, I simply **renamed a resource** (`banner.png` to `something_else_banner.png` since `banner.png` must have been reserved), and it worked!

Other things I tried that failed:

- Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32883231/2110869) by [mixel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746347/mixel), i tried to pngcrush and optipng my png that lead my to beleive that it could be an issue with my resources since the Gradle Console showed that the error occured during `:app:processDebugResources FAILED`.
- Build -> clean project Build -> rebuild project **failed**

Answer (score 1):

in my case:
I create new cordova project, then this aapt close in android studio,
then i just update SDK Build Tools to 23.0.3 latest version.
make sure you have installed MinSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion in android default 'sdk/build-tools' folder

Answer (score 1):

Android studio only accepts images within a certain file name frame

Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

I had a file by Korean. so I delete then It's worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

Always try to use the latest one for build tools. You have to change the line buildToolsVersion **"XX.X.X"** in **build.gradle** file (which generally resides under **mobile** directory in **gradle 2.0**) to the latest version : **23.0.2** or **24.0.2** or **25.0.2** (in my case). And then Rebuild Project. If you still have an issue, please try to update the corresponding build tool via **Android SDK Manager**.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your buildToolsVersion to latest and make sure your appcompactv7 import matches the sdk buildtoolversion. In my case it was buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'. Upgrading to it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. The solution was to move project folder into drive root folder. 
It looks like my project folder has huge path ("D:\DropBox\Dropbox\Video\Full Stack Web Development\Course 4 - Multiplatform Mobile App Development with Web Technologies\Week 3 - Deploying your App\Exercise 1\ionic\conFusion\").
After moving "Exercise 1" folder to the root of disk D, problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Change The buildToolsVersion To compileSdkVersion as Shown Below Code:...

Before: It Was Not Working....

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.kdmsl.kraapp'
        minSdkVersion 14
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.3"
        aaptOptions {
            additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
        }
    }
```

After Changes:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.kdmsl.kraapp'
        minSdkVersion 14
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.3"
        aaptOptions {
            additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, this problem cause by wrong resource in xml file, I suggest you return your code before everything is fine. then add your new code step by step and check xml file carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Have got the same error in React Native.I upgraded the android sdk version and resulted into this.

Root cause : old version's packager collect resources.

Solution : delete directories like 'drawable-xxxx' (ATTN：no 'v?' postfix) under $(rn_project)\android\app\src\main\re.

Reference :https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5787#issuecomment-236408669

Answer (score 0):

installing latest SDK/build-tool helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Add Below Library in gradle file .

> compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"
>   compile "com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2"

Answer (score 0):

I also have same error : 
"aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1"

In my code there was an mistake in layout xml file about drawable file name, after correct it. Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just used this `'android:drawableTop="2dp"'` with a `TextView`. Obviously, it is an invalid reference.
It is a good way to revert to the last git version when met with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I backtracked everything that I implemented and found that the issue was in the xml layout file that I was using for my login screen.

The relation that I had defined among the child views within the RelativeLayout(parent layout), was causing the error.

So the way to avoid such errors in future is to keep running/checking the code as soon as you implement anything, to avoid long backtracking(which was in my case).

Hope this would be of some help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, due to duplicated attributes in xml causes this issue. For example,

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello"
android:text="Hello" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent nearly 12 hour to find the resolution to this issue and finally I found the resolution.

This kind of supernatural issue, might happen in the below cases,

1. When your code has some problem, like sometimes IntelliJ/AndroidStudio does not report the compilation errors. Open each class and check for any compilation issues, these compilations issues will be because of not able to resolve few dependencies.
2. When you have a library that is latest, but you are referring to the oldest version.(Similar to point 1).
3. When you have a library that is dependent on some other library and that in turn referencing to old library, but your direct library is referring to newer version.
4. Importing from JFrog Artifactory, but your cache is not cleared, and you app is still holding to older version of .aar file
5. Your current gradle version of the app is latest, but you imported some other project as library and that version is older.
6. Your current gradle version of the app is latest, but you imported .aar file from jfrog artifactory and that is build from older gradle version.

when you are trying all the above cases, clean and build, or if this doesn't work, try "invalidate cache and Restart".

error like this will fall in some or the other above mentioned cases.

Happy Coding..!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was wrongly mentioned dp as d in dimension file. That cause this issue, once i corrected that value everything working fine. 
So due to some new added wrong values or files may cause this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced similar problem, got it fixed by disabling **"Instant Run"** option,

**File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Instant Run** 
Under Instant Run tab, disable **"Enable Instant Run to hot swap code.."**  [image]