# Android Studio: “libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited”

Tags: android, android-studio

I have upgrade gradle from :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
```

to :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta3'
    }
```

but I getting error :

```
AAPT err(Facade for 1057495093): E:\android_studio_workspace\P2JN\p2jn\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\reload_data.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1057495093): E:\android_studio_workspace\P2JN\p2jn\src\main\res\drawable\teamwork.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 2049818754): E:\android_studio_workspace\P2JN\p2jn\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_action_update.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 2049818754): E:\android_studio_workspace\P2JN\p2jn\src\main\res\drawable-ldpi\reload_data.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 2049818754): E:\android_studio_workspace\P2JN\p2jn\src\main\res\drawable\get_started.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
```

**edited** buildToolsVersion on my gradle project:

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

so how to fix it ?

Comment: Did my answer satisfy you? Could you accept it please?

Answer (score 8):

It's a warning that you png images has some invalid metadata.
Most simple and effective solution is to optimize your png images with [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) and [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net) utilities.

Run

```
pngcrush -ow -rem allb -brute -reduce image.png
```

and

```
optipng -o7 image.png
```

on every image that causes error.

On macOS and Linux you can use bash script that finds all png images in current directory and all its subdirectories and optimizes them:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `find . -name "*.png"`; do
    pngcrush -ow -rem allb -brute -reduce $i
    optipng -o7 $i
done
```

And for Windows save the following to batch file and run:

```
@echo off
set /p UserInputPath= What Directory would you like?
cd %UserInputPath%
for /r %%i in (*.png) do ( pngcrush -ow -rem allb -brute -reduce "%%i" & optipng -o7 "%%i" )
```

To install `pngcrush` and `optipng` on macOS use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager:

```
brew install pngcrush optipng
```

Comment: How do you install both `pngcrush` and `optipng` in MacOS?

Comment: @Pathros Added instructions.

Answer (score 0):

you should move the app icons to mipmap folder.

> It’s best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders (not the drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from the device’s current density.

Comment: They are indeed in mipmap- folders. However, I still get that error :/ `Emulator: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile` in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with upgrading the png library to 6.0 - it interpret the png files in a different way.

to fix it you should go through all of your png file to fix it.

Here is how I did it from command line:

```
brew install exiftool
cd /Drawable
find . -name "*.png" -exec exiftool -overwrite_original -all= "{}" ";"
```

Comment: In Android Studio, I still get that error :( `Emulator: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile`