# Android Studio AAPT err: libpng error: Not a PNG file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I have search all the possible available solution but still i am facing same issue with unclear error for me.

Now the complete error is-

**AAPT err(Facade for 370671127): libpng error: Not a PNG file
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.**

> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Now from this line **libpng error: Not a PNG file** actual i am not getting where is the problem exist either in my any image files or anything else except this.

**1-** Before posting this issues i have changed my all the images existing in the diff-2 folders in required **PNG formates** as I see as solution in other post.

**Note-** Its working fine on eclipse now I am importing this in Android Studio.

Since during project build only single(above) error is shown so I guess there is not should be any other issue. I have spend more time to resolve this issues so all the suggestions are welcomes for me.

Comment: remove recently added png file in your drawable or mipmap

Comment: @Sathish now i am getting the same old issues but with slightly diff. **AAPT err(Facade for 1757240286): D:\AndroidStudio\Workspace\VikramSingh1\app\src\main\res\drawable\calendar_tile_small.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited**

Comment: have you edited your png in MS paint?, Coz i got that issue when i edited on MS paint.

Comment: No, I have edited my all the images in adobe photoshop. after edit all the above  error has been removed except single one which I have post.

Comment: seems to be a bug in the new gradle 2 alpha. not sure if you use that one.
have a look at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=195047#makechanges

Answer (score 21):

The problem is in your png files. Probably you images were optimized by some png optimization tools. Android tools use **AAPT** tool to optimize images during building your project. The reason for this problem is that **AAPT** tool doesn't know that you preprocessed the image.

To get around this in your application you need to specify the option in gradle

```
  aaptOptions{
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
```

This is disable **AAPT** optimization for all of your png files.

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846901/libpng-error-not-a-png-file/37318591#37318591).

Answer (score 5):

Although there can be various reasons for this error , i.e **Can't resolve symbol R**

But In particular, If the problem is saying **Not a PNG file**

***My Case***

For me ,it was a **jpeg** file that I had saved with extension **.png** which was the root cause

***Solution***

**remove** that **jpeg** image from your **res/drawable** folder

**Note**

renaming a jpeg to png doesn't mean it is a png in android studio... so get rid of that jpeg image

rebuild..

voila.. it works

hope it helps :)

Comment: this will not help much as the name of the file to be changed from .jpeg to .png is not mentioned in the error logs. you can rename a specific file only if the file name is posted in error log. and since it is not there, its still an issue.