# How to resolve this error in android studio

Tags: android

AAPT err(Facade for 1353678858): C:\Users\GENIUS\AndroidStudioProjects\MultiUseApp\app\src\main\res\drawable\drawerback.png: libpng warning: sBIT: invalid

Comment: The error is of libpng , I think you can try changing the image because the error says sBIT invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer posted on [Android Studio AAPT err: libpng error: Not a PNG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218249/android-studio-aapt-err-libpng-error-not-a-png-file), if the .png file is actually a .jpeg that was renamed to a .png, you will get this error.