# Change Ionic App Icon

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Hello guys I'm trying to change my ionic app icon but I'm unable to do that. everytime I change the icon and make a build I get this error

```
:mergeDebugResourcesAAPT err(Facade for 260808337): libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 698764889): libpng error: Read Error
AAPT err(Facade for 698764889): libpng error: Read Error
AAPT err(Facade for 698764889): libpng error: Read Error
AAPT err(Facade for 698764889): libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 129342802): libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 129342802): libpng error: Read Error
AAPT err(Facade for 129342802): libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 506232339): libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 506232339): libpng error: Read Error
AAPT err(Facade for 370362787): libpng error: Not a PNG file
```

I have changed all the files from `resources/android/icon` and the icon.png file from `resources/icon.png` but I can't understand why am I getting this error. Please help me out

Comment: @ManuValdés yes I followed the instruction. I replaced the file in `resources/icon.png` and `resources/splash.png` with my own file and changed the name to the names the resources folder already had and then ran ionic resources.

Comment: @ManuValdés I have even placed the icon.png file inside the android folder but it's still throwing me the above error

Comment: The link is broken: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen/

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your original png file, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37318560/1016128). Make sure you don't do any preprocessing of the png file when you create it; in your image editor make sure you save it with the most compatible png options possible.

Comment: I haven't done any preprocessing with that file but that's a hd file image

Comment: can you please guide where should I place the option of the link you have given

Comment: no, that option is not for ionic, but the issue remains in your original png file