# Android Studio cannot compile

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Hello I have a problem in my Android Studio :

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Hady\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I try all but I can't solve this problem ..

My gradle file is like this :

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

[image]

My AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hadi.calculator">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: its res file error, what res files do you have..ie the xml ones

Comment: please see the picture i added to the question

Comment: Is there a reason you are using **buildToolsVersion** `19.1.0` instead of `23.0.2`?

Comment: I resolve this by simply removing identified errors in one of my xml files.

Comment: There's an answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36375675/2110869)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have a typo in `activity_main.xml`: `layout_heig8t`

Correcting the typo in your resource should clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

like Dalija said it's a result of a `build.gradle` dependencies conflict so please update your `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` to newest one.
Also you could (but this is highly not recommended) downgrade your support library version

Feel free to take a look at this issue: [Gradle finished with non zero exit value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value/30361914#30361914)

**EDIT:** Check also spelling of words to avoid mistakes like `heigh8t`

Comment: please can you tell me how to update compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion

Comment: Change your `buld.gradle` file like @dalija-prasnikar does. Next, open your `sdk manager` by clicking [this icon](http://documentation.kii.com/en/samples/push-notifications/push-notifications-android/configure-eclipse/as_toolbar_sdk_manager.png) and finally choose `Launch Standalone SDK Manager`. Check if `Android SDK Build tools` you installed are in the newest version. Than `Build -> Rebuild project`

Comment: If you have still a problem please update your screenshot or put in comment or next post a part of an app log with definition of issue

Comment: I see that problem you have is not only in layout, but also in Java class. Did you try to `Rebuild project`? Please add in next post full content of your `build gradle` file

Answer (score 0):

You are using `appcompat-v7:23.1.1`, you should upgrade your build tools and SDK versions to the latest.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

You can also remove SDK from Android manifest, because Gradle settings will override them and they are not needed.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

---

Additionally, pay attention to typos like heig8t, and take time to read and understand what error message is trying to tell you. Most of the times the answer will be right there.

If it says No resource identifier found for attribute `layout height`.. then it means that you have most likely spelled out `layout height` wrong. In this case it should be `android:layout_height`

Comment: Still not working , please see the photo i add it to the question

Comment: I added additional explanations. But if you ask question and answer resolves your primary error you should go and ask another question about new error (after you Google it first). This question has turned out to be endless debugging session and this is not how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

Please Open File-> Invalidate Cache/Restart the Android Studio It works fine