# Error - aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 android IONIC

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I created an application which first build was for IOS. So today my application is working well for IOS devices and is currently in app-store.

Yesterday I tried to build my application in android and I get this error :

```
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources/Users/OrcusZ/Documents/Ionic/NiceJob/NiceJob/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml:29:49-50 : AAPT: Color value not valid -- must be #rgb, #argb, #rrggbb, or #aarrggbb (at 'href' with value '#').

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/OrcusZ/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I found some topics in google but no one resolve my problem. If someone have a solution :)

Thanks

Comment: As you mentioned that this is happening for Android, it is gradle related issue. Clean and rebuild the project. Also try removing and adding platform again. Check this link too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873281/how-to-fix-23-0-1-aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1

Comment: I already tried to remove and add the platform, but nothing changed, moreover, i don't know how to clean a ionic android project..

Comment: dint have much exposure in ionic as I generally use vanilla Cordova. Will check and get back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this bug was related to the cordova-plugin-google-analytics I deleted it
and the compilation works