# Gradle build sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

What should i do?

```
:app:processDebugResources
C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\ishan\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(11) Error parsing XML: junk after document element
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:2 errors
Information:Total time: 5.789 secs
```

Comment: did you try this answer on stackoverflow...http://stackoverflow.com/a/34039593/3678308  ??

Comment: Add more detailed description what were you doing to get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error message says you have junk in your file `C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\ishan\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml` after the document element, so delete that junk.