# 28.0.3 aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, sdk, aapt

I have try to build project. But I am getting error Like this And I have got many reference. But I am not finding a proper solution for this.

below is error log.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'F:\Android_SDK\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

gradle.properties file

```
 # Project-wide Gradle settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.enableAapt2=false
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Comment: post your gradle.properties file

Comment: @sourabhkaushik i have add gradle.properties file.

Comment: I received this error after I deleted two vector images which were still used in project. I reverted the deleted files and the error disappeared .

Comment: For future readers of this question: ***DO NOT*** disable AAPT2. AAPT is deprecated and scheduled for removal (if it hasn't been already). Finding the AAPT2 logs is somewhat unintuitive, but they do exist, and it's a lot better than disabling it and using a deprecated system. This does also not answer the question, but it will avoid a lot of pain later.

Comment: Please check this one, the possibilities of error
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57656528/7181583

Comment: Please check this link, Possibilities for this error.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57656528/7181583

Answer (score 0):

change your gradle and google services version

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: what is distribution url in gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 0):

Please increase your

> gradle

version in `project module` to latest vesrion.It worked for me.

> ```
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Its happened to me. Solved by bring back some file that I delete not from Android Studio. After bring back the file and rebuild. its working for me

Answer (score -3):

File -> invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: I have Try invalidate caches and Restart. Not working

Comment: Are you using the latest build tools?, your compile SDK version and buildToolsVersion?